# Statistical difference between very small distributions

Tags: distributions, differences

I am evaluating machine learning classifiers with 4-cross validation due to very small dataset. Is there a way to determine if a classifier is better (other than F1 averages) from only 4 performance data points for each model?
Example of the data (models with F1 scores for every fold):

model1  0.730547    0.734663    0.743797    0.746269

model2  0.748173    0.730182    0.742915    0.759907

model3 0.7434   0.750359    0.745455    0.772257

If I do a standard one-way Anova test with p=0.05 these tests the distributions aren't significantly diffrent from each other. I fear that I can't use Anova in this case as I can't check the prerequisites of the test, other than the data being independent from each other.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "statistically better"?

Comment: This would mean, that distributions are different from each other, so you can say that the higher evaluating one is better, otherwise they would be the same. I updated my question with an example.

Comment: What classifiers are you comparing?

Comment: Missing from your description is the small sample size on which the models were built. Regardless, why wouldn't a bootstrap help answer your question? For example, Efron in his review of the work leading up to this innovation performed a bootstrap on a sample with fifteen observations. While I couldn't imagine doing a bootstrap on a human RCT with five or six patients, theoretically, it's possible.

Comment: I am using various machine learning models (SVC, KNN, FNN, CNN) to predict some class from my annotated data. I dont think bootstraping training is an option here, as it may take some time to complete a single training. And as far as I know bootstraping test set to do inference on it probably wont do anything, as I will get same evaluations for every data point, so I will just be approximating the current inference results?